# Is it an incorrect practice to use URL params as a way to fetch data using react router in an react application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express, axios, url-parameters

In my app I have a `Home` page that has a child named `Posts` the routes are set up in the following manner:

```
<Route path='/' element={<Home />}>
  <Route path='/posts/popular' element={<Posts />} />
  <Route path='/posts/new' element={<Posts />} />
</Route>
```

I would like to set it up where if I am on the `popular` path then my api call will be:

```
axios.get('/posts?sort=-popular')
```

But if I am on new, then the call would be:

```
axios.get('/posts?sort=-createdAt')
```

The way I was thinking of implementing it was to make the second param into a selector like:

```
<Route path='/' element={<Home />}>
  <Route path='/posts/:sortBy' element={<Posts />} />
</Route>

// in my Posts component I would call useParams
const {sortBy} = useParams();

// then in useEffect
axios.get(`/posts?sort=-${sortBy})
```

But this feels off, like I am doing it wrong. What is a better way, if any, of implementing this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you did is ok, but it will make the component harder to reuse, also if you changed the path you will need to change also the component `Posts`. It’s better to add a new prop `sortBy` inside your component `Posts` and pass the prop inside your `Route` component.

```
<Route path='/' element={<Home />}>
 <Route path='/posts/popular' element={<Posts sortBy="popular" />} />
 <Route path='/posts/new' element={<Posts sortBy="new"/>} />
</Route>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass props into the `<Posts />` component in your `Route`.

Here's an example:

```
<Route path='/' element={<Home />}>
  <Route path='/posts/popular' element={<Posts sort="popular" />} />
  <Route path='/posts/new' element={<Posts sort="createdAt" />} />
</Route>
```

Then inside `Posts` you can use the prop to determine which call to make:

```
const Props = ({ sort }) => {

// then in useEffect
axios.get(`/posts?sort=-${sort})
```